# What is an example of a non-regular, totally path-disconnected Hausdorff space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, examples

I need this for a counterexample: the multiplication in the fundamental group $\pi_1(\Sigma X_+)$, when it is equipped with the topology inherited from $\Omega \Sigma X_+$, fails to be continuous for the sort of space in the question, by a result from

> J. Brazas, The topological fundamental group and hoop earring spaces, 2009, arXiv:0910.3685

but the author doesn't supply an explicit example of such a space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the easiest examples is the rational numbers with the subspace topology of the real line with the K-topology. Total path disconnectedness is not entirely necessary for multiplication of $\pi_{1}(\Sigma X_{+})$ to fail to be continuous. It just makes the path component space of $X$ equal to $X$, greatly simplifying complications.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! I knew it would be something relatively simple, but I have little intuition for point-set topology. If we drop total path disconnectedness, what do we have to assume?

Comment: Well...you have to know something about the path component space $\pi_{0}^{top}(X)$ (the quotient of $X$ where path components are identified). It is good enough to know that $\pi_{0}^{top}(X)$ is Hausdorff but not completely regular to be sure that $\pi_{1}^{top}(\Sigma X_+)$ is not a topological group. Since $\pi_{0}^{top}$ is essentially surjective this gives a counterexample for every Hausdorff, non-completely regular space. There are much better examples (locally simply connected metric spaces even!) which would probably be more interesting. These will appear in a new version soon.

Answer (score 5):

There are several such examples in Steen and Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology*.  The first one I saw is number 60, the "relatively prime integer topology", consisting of the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ of positive integers, with a basis of sets of the form {b + na} where (a,b)=1 and n is an integer.

Comment: Should we make this a rule?  Before asking for a counterexample in topology, you should consult the book COUNTEREXAMPLES IN TOPOLOGY.

Comment: If the book were freely available on the internet, this would seem reasonable.  But it isn't, is it?

Comment: It's not freely available on the internet, to my knowledge, but, being a Dover book, it is available on the internet for very cheap:

http://www.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Topology-Lynn-Arthur-Steen/dp/048668735X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1273020303&sr=8-1

Comment: @PeteL.Clark A searchable database based on *Counterexamples* is available for free online: http://www.austinmohr.com/spacebook.

Comment: @Austin: great!