# A closed connected component in a topological space does not contain any path-connected subset?

Tags: gn.general-topology, tag-removed

Does there exist such a non-trivial closed connected component U of some connected topological space X or a non-trivial connected topological space X that do not contain any non-trivial path-connected subset.

The answer is negative if the space is assumed to be connected and locally path-connected. Since every component of a connected and locally path-connected space is path connected.

Added after some useful comments:
If we assume that the space X is actually a metric space (together with the metric topology), then can it possible to contain non-trivial path-connected subset. Note that i assume that any component of the metric space X is non-trivial (not a point).

Comment: @Changyu Guo: I think your question needs to be modified slightly, since a point is path-connected.

Comment: Wouldn't any countable connected space have this property (with U=X)?

Comment: To Mark Grant: Yes, i should add non-trivial path-connected subset-

Comment: To Goldstern: what do you mean by countable connected space? Is it a subclass of connected topological space? 

Comment: @Changyu Guo: If by "non-trivial" you mean "containing more than one point", then the one-point space is still problematic: it is a connected space which does not contain any "non-trivial" subsets!  

Comment: To Mark Grant: thanks for your reminder. I should also say that the connected component U or the space X in question is also non-trivial.

Comment: I think the question needs to be rewritten more clearly.

Comment: @Changyu Guo: See for instance http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-026-02/S0002-9939-1970-0263005-0/S0002-9939-1970-0263005-0.pdf and the references therein for the spaces Goldstern had in mind.

Comment: Consult Steen & Seebach for all types of topological counterexamples.  The automated index is "Spacebook" at http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146 ... set it for "connected but not path connected" to get the list of examples, and then if necessary examine these examples in the Steen & Seebach book itself.

Comment: (the question sounds like nonsense to me. Will anybody kindly rephrase it for me? Why does it speak of a connected component of a connected space?) 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for is a connected and totally path-disconnected space. Apparently there is such a beast on page 145 of "[Counter-examples in Topology](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X#reader_048668735X)" by Steen and Seebach (I don't have a copy of the book, and the page in question is missing from the linked preview).
It is amusingly called "Cantor's Leaky Tent" and is even a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

See also [What is an example of a non-regular, totally path-disconnected Hausdorff space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23430/what-is-an-example-of-a-non-regular-totally-path-disconnected-hausdorff-space)